# How to convert Set<String> to Set<Object>

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, type-conversion, set

How can I convert `strRoles` to `Set<Role>`. Thank you in advance

```
Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRoles();
Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

**Role.model**

```
@Document(collection = "roles")
public class Role {   
    @Id
    private String id;
    private ERole name;
}
```

**Erole.enum**

```
public enum ERole {
    ROLE_ADMIN,
    ROLE_USER
}
```

Comment: How does your Role object look like?

Comment: @Document(collection = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private ERole name;
}

Comment: I don't know how can I use strRoles as a Set Role> that's my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With streams:

```
Set<Role> convertStringSetToRoleSetWithStreams(final Set<String> rolesInString) {
    return rolesInString.stream().map(roleInString -> {
        final Role role = new Role();
        role.setName(ERole.valueOf(roleInString));
        return role;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Without streams:

```
Set<Role> convertStringSetToRoleSetWithoutStreams(final Set<String> rolesInString) {
    final Set<Role> rolesInObject = new HashSet<>();
    for (final String roleInString : rolesInString) {
        final Role role = new Role();
        role.setName(ERole.valueOf(roleInString));
        rolesInObject.add(role);
    }
    return rolesInObject;
}
```

Feel free to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Wondering, how did you conclude the setting the value as `role.setName(ERole.valueOf(roleInString))` without a mention in the question?